# "unique to what has come before it"

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

What do "unique to what has come before it" mean in this context?

> What is blockchain?
>
> Blockchain is a record keeping system – a ledger – where multiple sources validate an entry before it gets added.
>   Once it’s added, it can’t be changed, and the record is distributed, living in multiple places at once.
>
> There are several features here that *are unique to what has come before it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think this is an example of poor English.

"Unique" literally means that something is the only example of its kind; unlike anything else. One cannot have gradations of "uniqueness" - something either *is* unique, or it *is not*.

When speaking about the quality of uniqueness you can attribute it *to* something, for example:

> This feature is unique to our system.

But in your example it seems like the writer is trying to use "unique" as a comparative term:

> There are several features here that are unique to what has come before it.

This doesn't make any sense because if a feature was unique to something else (whatever system or version came before this one) then it cannot be a feature of *this* system too or it would not be unique.

If I was to rewrite this I would say:

> There are several features that are unique to this system, and unlike any system that has come before it.